# Search for specific symbol inside array

Tags: php, search

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', /*... letters from 3 alphabets*/);

$letter = 'some symbol, posted by user'; // real length = 1
```

**How to get know, is `$letter` one of the symbols, listed in `$array`?**

Like, if `$letter = 'G'` and there is no `G` in `$array`, well then `return false`.

---

Yep, I tried `in_array()`, but there are too many symbols, is there any other (shorter) solution?

Comment: You could try splitting each alphabet into it's own $array, and then just do a bunch together... but there shouldn't be a limit on the amount of items in an array.

Comment: letters and symbols like '!, ?' etc

Comment: I guess you mean shorter as in processing time, I've updated my answer to give you another way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in_array() http://ca.php.net/in_array

```
if(in_array($letter,$array)) {
  // your code
}
```

Another method would be to do this

```
// THIS WAY
$array = array('a','b','c'); // and continue this way. 
$array = array_flip($array);

// OR THIS
$array = array('a'=>0,'b'=>0,'c'=>0);

// This will stay the same
if($array[$letter] != null) {
  // your code
}
```

Comment: You can turn the letters array into keys with `array_flip()` instead.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock, I've never run into a need for this, but it might come in handy. I've updated my answer to include your method as well.

Comment: It should be `$array = array_flip($array);` as that function does not modify the parameter. (Nitpicking, I know.)

Comment: Totally valid though, someone might stumble into this and end up posting about it again because it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$IsInArray = in_array($letter, $array); //RETURNS TRUE OR FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function ... lets you find a needle (single letter) in a haystack (an array)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a string instead of an array:

```
$letters = 'abcdefghi...';
$letter = 'a';

if (false !== strpos($letters, $letter)) {
    // valid letter
}
```